# Transform ["a=b","c=d","e=f"] to {"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"} in rego

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have an array as defined below

```
        ["dev=devA",
        "instance=instanceA",
        "domain=domainA",
        "namespace=namespaceA",
        "service=serviceA"]
```

I want an object in kv format, as defined below

```
        {"dev"="devA",
        "instance"="instanceA",
        "domain"="domainA",
        "namespace"="namespaceA",
        "service="serviceA"}
```

I tried to `{x | x := split(str, "/")[_]}` used `sprintf` to print out. However, the `sprintf` want `array[any]`, now the input is `set[string]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object comprehension:

```
package policy

arr := ["dev=devA",
        "instance=instanceA",
        "domain=domainA",
        "namespace=namespaceA",
        "service=serviceA"]
        
obj := {k: v |
    item := arr[_]
    [k, v] := split(item, "=")
}
```

Full example at the [Rego Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/gd0q3nFVMt).

Comment: I wish the doc could be little better with more examples.

Comment: Yeah, although it's always hard when you're not sure what to search for. Here's the doc on object comprehensions: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#object-comprehensions

Comment: The OPA Slack is another great resource if you're looking for community discussions on OPA and Rego.